# how can i add multiple click on back pressed button

Tags: android, back-button, onbackpressed

How can I add multiple backpressed button like when i press back button that show me PRESS DOUBLE CLICK TO EXIT after toast message when i click double on press button then the app exit... i did this method but its just twice to exit the app i want to implement 3 times

```
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce){
        super.onBackPressed();
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    }

    else {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Double Press to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Can you check if this works?
Override onBackPressed to increment a variable and exit if its count is 2.
eg.

int pressCount=0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    count++;
    if(count==2){
     super.onBackPressed();  
     count=0;     
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that way:

```
    int counter = 0;


    ....

    public void onBackPressed() {
                        counter++;
                        if(counter > 2){
                            System.exit(0);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(this, "TRIPLE CLICK TO EXIT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                        }

                        final long DELAY_TIME = 3000L;
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run(){
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(DELAY_TIME);
                                    counter = 0;
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that seems super hacky from a UI perspective, but if you really want to do that an easy way might be something like:

```
Integer backToExitPressedCounter = 0

...

if(backToExitPressedCounter==3){
    super.onBackPressed();
    backToExitPressedCounter = 0;
} else {
    backToExitPressedCounter++;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Triple Press to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: No problemo! Good luck!

Comment: I think this is not so good solution. If you press three times back button but they are not in short period of time (for example You where click back button three times per a minute) the exit will be called, but that is not expected behavior.

Comment: Ya I think yours would be a more useful implementation, but that's not what OP asked for. And in any case, all of this is terrible UI design anyway. When a user clicks a button they expect an action to take place, not to have to click it three times. It's completely inconsistent design from the rest of Android and violates numerous design principles such as Feedback, Affordance, and Mapping. OP should implement a custom UI element that affords triple clicking.